# "Unknown filesystem" error and grub rescue prompt on boot

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 alongside Windows 7. When I restarted my pc it showed unknown file system and grub> . I googled it and found something after which it is showing only grub>
Now I'm using a live cd and trying to find any other solutions. All the files in partition where Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 are installed, are present. Also, I'm posting the output of fdisk -l, I hope that will help.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
224 heads, 19 sectors/track, 229504 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0bc187fb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   102399999    51096576    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       102400000   307199999   102400000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       307202046   976771071   334784513    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       307202048   512002047   102400000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       664348672   675837951     5744640   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       675846144   839686143    81920000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       839688192   976771071    68541440    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda9       512004096   660273151    74134528   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      660275200   664336383     2030592   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 4002 MB, 4002910208 bytes
32 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3878 cylinders, total 7818184 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x01443411

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63     7818047     3908992+   b  W95 FAT32
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the output from the boot info script: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself at this prompt:

`grub rescue>`

It helps to run

```
grub rescue>set
prefix=(vg0-whatever)/boot
root=vg0-whatever
```

If those aren't correct use the `set` command to change them:

```
grub rescue>set prefix=(vg0-root)/boot
grub resuce>set root=vg0-root
```

At that point you can load the "normal" module and resume booting.

```
grub rescue>insmod normal
grub rescue>normal
```