# Unknown filesystem error: grub rescue

Tags: grub2, filesystem, testdisk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

After using testdisk 6.11, I got the error message:

```
Unknown filesystem error: grub rescue
```

To fix it, I used Boot-Repair, but it took too long - hours! (I had to go to sleep and return (: )

So, is there other way to fix it faster?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try again with Boot Repair.

### 1 - Live CD

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

### 2 - Repair the bootloader

To restore the Grub bootloader, follow these steps.

Open a terminal from the Live CD, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running now.

Comment: I did it at first but as I said, his scan (after "boot-repair" command) has taken too long, is there other ways?

Comment: Well, you can always run `sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt; sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdx; sudo update-grub` from the Live CD, where **sdx** is the identifier for your disk and **sdx1** is the Ubuntu partition's identifier.

Comment: if my boot is on the xp partition, and i'm doing it, it'll be okey? will it delete the old boot from there or i will have 2 boot partition?

Comment: No, this will install Grub to your disk's MBR.

Comment: sorry to missunderstand, but its not okey or wont make 2 boot partition?

Comment: Installing Grub to the MBR does not create an additional partition. The MBR is a special sector of your hard disk that contains the code that launches your OS when the computer boots.