# Installing Windows 8 over 12.04, but getting "error: unknown filesystem"

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

I have had bad experiences with 12.04 on my laptop, too many things just don't work so am wiping it and replacing with Windows 8 release preview to get it running again. Anyway, I installed normally, deleted partitions and formatted and installed Windows fine, but now there is an error coming up when it boots:

```
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

I've tried repairing from Windows 8 disk, doing FixMbr and FixBoot but that hasn't worked, and neither has reinstalling.

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Comment: Boot from a Ubuntu LiveCD and open a terminal, type `sudo fdisk -l` and post the results on your question.

Comment: The standard behavior of Windows is to write its own boot loader to the MBR on installation. Unless Windows 8 has added an option not to do this, you may have found a bug in the Windows 8 Release Preview. You could see what help is available through Microsoft support, and in forums for users of Windows 8. Otherwise, creating a new partition table on your drive (with GParted on the Ubuntu live CD) will wipe everything out, but should fix the problem. I'm posting this as a comment rather than an answer with the hope that someone will be able to furnish more helpful advice.

Comment: Results of sudo fdisk -l:

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000726f0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   976771071   488384512    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 8036 MB, 8036285952 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 977 cylinders, total 15695871 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          44    15679439     7839698    b  W95 FAT32

Comment: Sorry, how to I enter this and retain format? backticks doesnt seem to work?

Comment: @ShaneO'Connor The best way is to provide the information by editing your question to include it. While `backticks do work in comments`, this information really belongs in your question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> You’ll need to get your Windows 7 or Windows Vista retail disc or
>   download the free recovery media from NeoSmart.net
>
> Note: If you don’t have a retail disc with your computer, and instead
>   you had to make a recovery media with your PC, don’t worry – you can
>   download a Windows 7/Vista recovery disc that allows you to do the
>   same thing with a retail disc – except reinstall Windows of course:
>   see http://neosmart.net/blog/2009/windows-7-system-repair-discs/ for
>   Windows 7 and
>   http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/
>   for Windows Vista. It’s in ISO format that you can easily burn to a
>   disc.
>
> Put the disc in, then as it comes up to the installation section (for
>   retail discs), click “Repair my computer” then go and select your
>   Windows installation, and from there select Command Prompt. For the
>   recovery media discs you downloaded from NeoSmart – we’re not sure
>   what the steps are, but it’s probably similar.
>
> Then you need to type:
>
> Note: execute one command at a time
>
> bootrec.exe /FixBoot
>
> bootrec.exe /FixMbr
>
> It takes less than a second. Reboot and it’ll boot into Windows
>   automatically. Then go to Start menu, right click Computer and select
>   Manage. Go to Disk Management from here, and delete the partitions
>   related to Ubuntu. Once you’ve done this, extend the volume size of
>   your Windows partition to take the remaining free space. To
>   delete/extend volume size of a partition, you right click.

Source: http://blog.eukhost.com/webhosting/howto-remove-grub-loader-and-restore-windows-7-and-vista-bootloader/