# Grub loading unknown file system grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

I am new to Linux. I had Windows 7 installed in my laptop. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 9.0 from a free CD I got. I choose the option "Install side by side with Windows 7 loader (something like that..)". Everything went fine & I installed Ubuntu. When I restarted, I could easily boot from both Windows 7 & Ubuntu.

But later when I booted from Windows 7, I did a disk management by right clicking "my Computer" & choosing the option "Manage". Actually I deleted a drive & added that empty volume in another drive.

Now when I start my system it shows the following error:

```
Grub loading
Unknown file system
grub rescue>
```

I have no clue what to do now. Please help me at urgent.

Any solution in **layman's language** is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I want all my files on both Windows 7 & Ubuntu.