# Stuck With grub rescue> console

Tags: grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

Here is the background of my issue:

I just recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu along side with Windows 8 Enterprise. However upon checking the disk size, it seems that some of the portions of the hd memory were gone so I decided to check the disk partition and have seen that is was being used by another file system. Thinking that the Ubuntu takes it boots stuff from my drive C: , I deleted that partition and formated so I can use it to store some movies, music etc.

Now, as I switch on my machine, I am stucked with:

```
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

I googled a lot and saw the following command which seems no  to me like sudo, chainloader etc, all of these command only returns unknown command in the console.

What I just wanted is to boot from my Windows 8 OS.

Just to add, I can't open the BIOS menu so I could choose what media to boot. As I open my machine it automatically takes me to grub rescue console.

Here are the thing I already have:

- Ubuntu Installation Disk
- Windows 8 System repair Disk

I just don't know how to boot into these things.  Let me know what to do.

Comment: There has to be a way to boot from another medium during POST, which every desktop and laptop computer performs. Is this a computer from your company that is eventually locked down to not boot from other media? What is the model name of the computer?

Answer (score 0):

grub is only loaded after bios loads. So there must be ways to goto bios. Maybe your monitor starts too late. Please consult your motherboard manual to go to bios mode. Generally it's del key. Keep pressing it just after switching on the pc. Boot in win 8 and perform a startup repair.

or boot using ubuntu and use "boot-repair" program to repair both linux 
 windows.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this issue. Before installing Ubuntu, i can manage to access bios mode by pressing F2, but now the message which tell me what button to press to access bios setup doesn't even show up when my laptop boots.

Comment: so i was hoping that i could boot from Window 8 on grub rescue > command line.

Comment: No You can't.repeatedly press  f2 after powering up. You must know no operating system can modify bios. Bios is in the motherboard rom while operating system works from hard disk. BIOS load Os. Anyhow the prompt isn't coming. But do as I told, you will get access to bios