# error: unknown filesystem / grub rescue>

Tags: grubrescue

My hard drive blew out a couple of months back. I bought a new one today and I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 and put it on a USB. I tried to boot from my flash-drive because it always works. The grub menu does not pop up, (also my USB had to be formatted which deleted the file of Ubuntu I used to have) and I'm guessing it's either a bad version of the OS, or dragging it from folder to folder did not move GRUB with it too, or maybe one of my other drives blew out as well, or something else. I have no clue.

If any questions need to be asked, let me know. I also bought a recovery disk that's supposed to come in within the next week or two. I'm also trying to partition my HDD to run Ubuntu and Windows on a dual-boot but I haven't acquired windows yet. But if someone could help me get passed the `grub rescue` part.

Also, the only command that works after `grub rescue>` is `ls`. Nothing else works. And when I type in `ls`, it gives me like 3 or 4 hd0* stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

To make a USB bootable, intead of simply copying the contents from an ISO, you must use a utility such as `unetbootin`, which can be found [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Download, follow the prompts, and you should have a fully working Live CD.  But be sure to format the USB first.