# grub rescue> error : unknown filesystem

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I had a laptop with windows 7 and linux operating systems. but i deleted the drive where linux is installed when operating in windows os. Now i am getting grub rescue>
I need to enter the windows os without this grub interruption, I also need the commands to be entered in grub rescue>. I want this done without losing the windows 7 os and files in the hard disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Download `boot-repair` live disk from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) .And make it bootable through usb.
After booted up click on `Recommended repair` option,it will reinstall your grub.You won't loss any windows files during this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You've deleted the installation folder /boot/grub when wiping your linux partition. However, grub is still written in the MBR. If you want to get rid of grub ultimately, you need to install the Windows bootloader and overwrite your MBR. You can do this using a windows 7 boot medium.
If you don't have one, i think there are some windows rescue images on the internet, which should work as well.