# How to solve Grub rescue

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

in my system there was windows 7-32 bit and linux tamil (Govt laptop) I deleted the linux partition from windows by Disk Management in windows. when i rebooted the system i get the follwing Thing,

GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

Pls help me to solve this issue and access me to Windows

Comment: please try boot-repair disk.see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/371961/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem/371967#371967