# unknown filesystem, grub rescue

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, grub2, grubrescue

When I try to boot I get this message:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue> _
```

results of:

```
grub rescue> ls
```

are as follows:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (fd0)
```

Comment: Hey I am having the same problem as you had of grub rescue how did you fixed it? can you explain me.

Comment: Honestly, user2014111, I actually had to copy the files off of the HDD, and then I re-installed the whole OS. Sorry I couldn't be of more help... -Chandler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't know your Ubuntu boot partition, check them one by one:

```
ls (hd0,msdos5)/
ls (hd0,msdos1)/
```

When you hit the right one, you'll get a line mentioning "lost+found" and so on.

Assuming (hd0,msdos5) is the right partition:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Now you'll be able to boot into Ubuntu. Once you do, reinstall GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: I ran the first two commands with (hd0,1) in place of (hd0,5) as (hd0,msdos1) was the correct partition... they produced no message so I assumed they worked, but when I ran insmod normal... it gave me this message: error: file not found. Then I ran the normal command and it rebooted to the same problem (unknown filesystem) I am running 12.04 LTS Server Version if that changes anything. Thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind that. I got it fixed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ur wlcm. Plz mark as answered.

Comment: Hi Chadler..i am getting file not found error when i type insmod normal. please help me

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, I have not been on StackExchange in months. You, Ekaveera, may already have it fixed, but if not, I can try to help you. However, I had the same error. I believe those instructions are for an outdated version of Ubuntu. Easiest fix is to wipe the OS and then re-install. -Chandler

Comment: I show `(hd0), (hd0,1), ...` None show an `msdos` and running `ls (hd0,n)` for each `n` produces `error: unknown filesystem.` any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a UEFI bios make sure you boot through uefi boot and not legacy. Grub is actually there but the bios doesn't allow it to start

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i found to fix this error was to put in an old windows 98 disk and in dos you can delete and create partitions and then format