# No boot device found press any key to reboot machine - dual boot Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I have installed Windows OS in UEFI and Ubuntu in Legacy.

After some time I got an error when I tried to boot in Ubuntu.

```
error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue> _
grub rescue>
```

I solved this issue - [unknown filesystem, grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375801/unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue)

```
set root=(hd0,gpt7)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

But when I tried to reinstall Grub using

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Error : -

```
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; 
embedding won’t be possible.
```

After that I created a partition using

```
parted /dev/sda set 1 bios_grub on
```

and installed grub using

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

And that's when the problem started. When I tried to boot into Windows in UEFI mode
following error appears:

```
No boot device found press any key to reboot machine.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: If you really want to boot Ubuntu in BIOS mode, you need a separate 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. Better to have Ubuntu in UEFI mode. If sda1 was your efi partition you then overwrote it with parts of grub and have to restore the FAT32 formatted partition with the boot flag and repair it with a Windows repair disk. This will not fix Windows issues but will show details. Post link to summary report: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> After that I created a partition using `parted /dev/sda set 1 bios_grub on`

The command you specified did ***not*** create a partition; instead, it marked your *existing* first partition as a [BIOS Boot Partition,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition) which GRUB uses by writing part of itself directly to the partition, without using a filesystem. Thus, when you re-installed GRUB, you ***trashed your existing first partition!*** That partition was probably either your [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) where your EFI boot loaders go, or perhaps some other Windows-specific boot partition.

There's a slim chance that you can overcome this problem by resetting the type code on your first partition and using `dosfsck` or some other filesystem-recovery tool on it; but you may need to re-create the partition's contents from scratch. This is possible, but tricky. I don't have a URL handy to a procedure, but try a Web search on terms like "fixing damaged EFI System Partition." The ESP is basically a FAT partition that holds EFI boot loaders, which are ordinary files, so the recovery procedure will involve laying down a fresh FAT filesystem and restoring the files by copying them from another source or using a Windows recovery tool.

As a meta-comment, installing Linux in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode to a computer that already has Windows running in EFI/UEFI mode is doing things the hard way, at best. It's much better to install both OSes in the same mode, as described [in this page I wrote.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) If you hadn't trashed your ESP, it would be relatively simple to add an EFI boot loader for Linux to the ESP to work around your initial problem, but now you've got to restore your Windows boot loader, and possibly adjust your boot loader NVRAM entries.

Good luck!