# GRUB issue with 12.04 installed on WD Passport

Tags: 12.04, grub2

Having trouble getting Ubuntu to boot from my external hard drive. Installed fine from live CD but upon booting I got "error: unknown filesystem" and it gave me a grub rescue> prompt.

After a bit of reading I stumbled across answers like this [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem) but my problem is running ls doesn't even show the drive that I've installed on.

I've tried reinstalling several times and I tried running boot-repair and it made no difference. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong or is this likely to be some sort of hardware incompatibility?

Comment: Do you have a rather old PC? If yes, I'd check whether "USB Legacy Emulation" is enabled in your BIOS setup

Comment: It's a Core 2 Duo system, so it's not THAT old. I can boot fine from other USB devices.