# Stuck on Grub Rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

Ok, I know there are lots of answer on that topic, but I've been trying to get out of that for ages with no luck.
What happened was that, I had an Ubuntu 14.04 in one partition and windows 7 in another. It was working perfectly, then I needed to downgrade to 12.04, what I did was create yet another partition for that. Everything was working fine, but not satisfied I decide to delete everything and just stay with the windows and then reinstall ubuntu 12.04.
Being a complete noob, I opened windows, deleted both ubuntus disks, and restarted my computer. Ever since then I'm in this grub rescue think. I did some research and realized I did something very stupid, and have been trying to solve the problem ever since.
I don't have a CD drive to put a windows installation CD on, but I created bootable USB sticks (I tried with windows and both versions of ubuntu) it did not work, whenever I put an USB stick nothing happens.
Then I tried the commands on the screen. It goes like that:

```
ls
(hd0), (hd0,msdos3), (hd0,msdos2), (hd0,msdos1)
ls (hd0,msdos3)
no filestream
ls (hd0,msdos2)
no filestream
ls (hd0,msdos1)
no filesream
```

I'm really lost here. Please, if anyone can help I'd be so happy!

Answer (score 0):

Repair solve your problem.

**1st option : get a disk including Boot-Repair**

The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to burn one of the following disks and boot on it.

```
Boot-Repair-Disk is a disk starting Boot-Repair automatically.

Boot-Repair is also included in Linux-Secure-Remix.
```

Remark : you can also install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer).

**2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

- either from an Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu") or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)
- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

  ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
  ```

**Using Boot-Repair**

Recommended repair

```
launch Boot-Repair from either :
    the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)

    or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
    or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal 

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.
```

This will work for me. I hope this is help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the discussion here:

[Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem?newreg=463cac52d4ae436c8cc58708fa35a9ce)

If it still not working.

Try these steps:

- Load live cd/USB (https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)
- Repair filesystem (maketecheasier.com/check-repair-filesystem-fsck-linux/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. ALSO: DO NOT self-advertise here. Thanks.