# After uninstalling ubuntu i can't enter any system. Grub rescue error: unknown file system

Tags: grub2, system

I used to have Windows 8. I installed ubuntu (14.04 to be exact). Soon, ubuntu was messed up. So I tried to install a new system. I deleted the ubuntu partition and now whenever I try to boot my pc it comes up like this:

```
error: Unknown filesystem
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

*NOTE*: I do not have a system. But i have a Ubuntu and Windows 7 CD ready in case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Of course! You erased the boot loader, so nothing can boot. you have two options:

1. If you want to install Ubuntu again, just do it! That will install a new grub over the broken one!
2. If you don't want to install Ubuntu, insert Windows 8 disk and repair the boot loader from it. I'm not sure if you can do it with Windows7 disk or not!

Comment: But Danial i cnan't install anything.

Comment: @HatMan , Do you know how to boot from Disk?