# Grub rescue trouble after moving a partition

Tags: boot, grub2

So I was allocating some free space for ubuntu and now grub is launching in rescue mode.  I have done a lot of searching and tried what has been suggested here several times.

[Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

However, I have tried every ls (hdX,msdosY) possibility and all of them return a "Filesystem is unknown" message, all except for (hd0,msdos4) which returns "Filesystem is ext4."

I have booted in with a live version and have confirmed that the files are all there.  I am of the understanding that what is needed is to associate the directory path of the grub modules in the root folder.

Comment: type `set` and see what it says the root and prefix variables are set to.

Comment: I typed "set" and it says "cmdpath=(hd0)     prefix =(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub    root = hd0,msdos5,  When I type "ls" it shoes (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1).  Sorry about this comment formatting.

Comment: Also, this seems silly, but in the original post I had posted the wrong link.  Should be http://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `hd0,4` is where you have ubuntu installed ( your root filesystem, and it also contains /boot ), then it seems that grub has the wrong prefix ( did it move since installing grub? ).  At the rescue prompt, type `set prefix=(hd0,msdos4)/boot/grub`, then `insmod normal` and finally `normal` and that should get you to the normal grub prompt so you can boot up.  Once booted, to fix this in the future, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` to reinstall grub to the MBR with the correct prefix setting.

Comment: Well done; that was it!  Thanks.  I had already typed that in like three times already, but I had neglected to add the 'normal' command.  So I had actually changed it, but I guess it never actually got the chance to execute...

Comment: That worked on a Xubuntu 18.04 system as well with a minor modification: If your /boot and / are on /dev/sda4, then set prefix=(hd0,4)/boot/grub.  Mine were on /dev/sda1 so I set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub. The other instructions worked for me as-is.