# How to deal with "'normal.mod' not found" in grub rescue?

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

Yesterday my PC suddenly freezed and when I restarted I was faced with the Grub Rescue. So I started trying ways provided in this site to make it to the boot menu.

First I tried to find where my Ubuntu was installed. But then when i tried the **ls (hd0,2)/boot** command for every listed partition, every time I got this **error: unknown filesystem**. It was unclear.

So I took someone's advise and tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1uet.jpg). Hence since I was being shown the directories in **ls (hd0,3)/**, I assumed boot should be in (hd0,msdos3).

And then I went on with some steps to get to boot menu when suddenly [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ91w.jpg) happened.

Since then I have not been able to find any solution to fix this 'normal.mod' problem. I think this is the last step to fixing the problem but right now I am at a dead end.

Please help.

P.S- If it helps I had only Linux Mint installed. No dualboot system.

Answer (score 0):

From [yesterday's question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811854/how-can-i-find-where-my-ubuntu-installed?noredirect=1#comment1227644_811854):

According to the screenshot shared by you:

[image: Image 1]

You have three partitions on your hard-drive, presumably:

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sda3
```

Now, according to the outputs of the `ls` command it is clear that:

1. `/dev/sda1` is not an `EXT` file system.
2. `/dev/sda2` is also not an `EXT` file system.
3. Though, `/dev/sda3` is an `EXT` file system for some reasons there is `/boot` folder in it.

Now, according to today's output:

[image: Image 2]

`/dev/sda3` is your `home` partition. It means that during your last installation of Ubuntu you created a separate partition for `home` and as such all your data is safe. Also, this means that for some unknown reasons your Ubuntu partition got corrupted while still in use.

SOLUTION:

There is only one solution to this - a new installation of Ubuntu.

But, do not worry as most of your data is still safe as your `home` partition is still intact. The only things you will loose are the installed softwares and your username, password and other minor things which you can install easily after a fresh install.

P.S.: When you will do a fresh install, the part when you are asked about partition, choose 'Something else' and then choose `/dev/sda3` as your `home` partition and everything should be alright.

Comment: Yes I remember creating different partitions: for root, swap space and home. There is one more question I would like to ask, I had Linux Mint (17.3 maybe) installed before. So which version should I install now?  It would be great if you just share the link from the download page... :)

Comment: @Shadow_Sphynx - [Link to new iso](https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=217).

Comment: Sorry for being this late.I had been out fr some time.

So while installing this is what I am getting:

[link](http://imgur.com/a/TyY6g)

What should I do now?