# Tried to re-install Ubuntu, Ubuntu and Windows 10 failing to load. Grub Rescue screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I had Windows 10 (which I use primarily) on one drive of my computer and Ubuntu 16.04 on another drive.  I updated Ubuntu to 17.10, but it would crash shortly after starting up.  Now, what I did next is probably what caused the rest of my problems and I will never do it again, but I'm hoping someone can help me through it.

In Windows, I deleted all of the partitions on my Ubuntu drive and planned to reinstall.  The reinstall ended with the same freezing problem, but when I restarted I was greeted with:

```
error: no such device: (series of letters and numbers which I assume is the device)
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I have tried looking around for solutions and it appears I have removed Grub.  I have a bootable USB that can boot to the "try Ubuntu without installing" without it crashing, but I can't follow the other answers I've found.

I would like to return to a state where I only have Windows so I can try to get Ubuntu to work at a later time.

Edit: I should clarify that I already attempted to use ls in the rescue mode screen.  All of the (hdX,msdosY) returned an error.  Also sudo-installing grub did not work either.

Edit2: Looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem) question, I found that all of my drives/partitions returned:

```
Filesystem is unknown.
```

Other than (hd1,msdos6) and (hd1,msdos1) which returned:

```
Filesystem is ext2
```

I am not sure which of these is Windows and which is Ubuntu.  Can I try the solution in the link for either or is there something else I should do first?

Edit3: I tried the code in Update 3 of the linked solution with both of the ext2 filesystems.  Both returned:

```
file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
```

Comment: What you want is called dual boot. Helping you here would result more in a chat than some straight answer. Hence, try Google with a step-by-step instruction for installing Windows and Linux side by side. It's really not that difficult. As for Windows it depends on what you did. Speaking from own experience, you might want to reinstall everything cleanly and setup a nice partitioning for the dual boot.

Comment: @Jordan You might also wanna try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNeJvujdB-0

Comment: @Socrates I had it working before and believe I get get it working again.  Right now I can't get it to boot to anything I really don't want to have to reinstall windows.

Comment: @dessert I tryed to reinstall grub that way.  Didn't change anything.

Comment: @Jordan Ok, if you are sure that you problem lies within grub, you might wanna try the rescuing Grub as suggested by *dessert*. Using the live installation you'll have to root into your system and re-run a Grub update that finds all your local systems automatically. If done well, you'll get a choice of OS's at boot. Otherwise an error, that you could post here.

Comment: @Jordan What way exactly? Did you try [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? Please [edit] and clarify what exactly you tried!.

Comment: @Socrates I'm going to give this another go and will document it and make another edit.  Sorry if I'm clear, I hardly understand the issue.  Thank you!

Comment: @dessert I have not tried boot repair as I haven't been able to get into either OS.  Could I make it work through the "try ubuntu" on a bootable USB?

Comment: Using boot-repair is much easier then trying to do this manually.  Follow Dessert's original suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Boot repair, as suggested by @dessert was absolutely the way to go.  I ran it from "try ubuntu" on my bootable USB.  Thank you so much for the help!