# How to solve this GRUB error?

Tags: grub2

I used Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 in a dual boot setup. Now I am uninstalling Ubuntu because of some errors. After I have deleted the Ubuntu OS volumes, I restarted my system. But after restarting, the GRUB prompt appears.

What happened and how to solve this?

Comment: You must have deleted a volume that contained grub. Just search how to restore Windows bootloader, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.