# How can I boot from a usb key when all I can get is a Ubuntu grub rescue prompt?

Tags: boot, grubrescue

My Acer Aspire One D270-1596 boots to a grub rescue prompt.
I've been able to set root and prefix to get to the Ubuntu 18.04 grub (?) page and memory test menu, but running Ubuntu or a restore version fails to find /root/dev and says target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.

Typing "ls" at grub rescue> gives me HD0 partitions called hd0,msdos6, 5, 3, 2 and 1.

Typing "set" from grub rescue> tells me:
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
root=(hd0,msdos7)

Typing ls (hd0,msdos7) tells me "error: no such partition"

Typing ls (hd0,msdos5 or 6) tells me both Filesystems 5 and 6 are ext2.
All other partitions say "Filesystem is unknown"

Setting the prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub and root=(hd0,msdos5) then insmod normal and normal get me to the Ubuntu grub menu.

Doing this for (hd0,msdos6) tells me "error: /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found".
Doing it for (hd0,msdos7) says there is no such partition, even though (hd0,msdos7) is presented using the "set" command.

Choosing "Ubuntu" or other versions in the GRUB menu on (hd0,msdos5) says "mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory" and takes me to BusyBox v1.21.1 and a prompt (initramfs) where "help" gives me a long list of commands that mean nothing to me.

I have a bootable USB key for Ubuntu 18.04 which I used to install Unbuntu on another computer. (The one I'm using now to try to recover my Acer.)

It shows up as (hd1) at "ls" at grub rescue> if plugged into the Acer, with one partition, (hd1,msdos2)
The (hd1,msdos2) partition shows as an unknown file system.

Pressing F2 (or F12 or F10) while booting the Acer does not take me to the BIOS menu so I could boot from the USB key.
This seems to me to be the most straightforward way to resolve this problem. Can anyone recommend a way to get to the BIOS menu since the built in prssing of F2 doesn't work?

This is (was!) a perfectly good computer with 2 GB of RAM and a 360 GB hard drive that I would like to recover even if I might lose what's on the hard drive already.

Can anyone help me?

Bob Thomson
Ottawa Canada

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly then your problem/question is that you can't figure out how to access your BIOS settings.  Unfortunately this is something that is specific to your motherboard, so you need to pay special attention to the boot splash screen for instructions how to do this.  Or you will need to consult with your motherboard documentation how to access the menu and how to change the boot priority to boot from your USB.

Comment: Normally, it can be when starting your computer, spam press (repeatedly press) either, ESC, F1, F10, DEL  (not at the same time, but try once,  spam press ESC, doesn't   work -> shut down, startup p and press F1, etc..)   Hope this will be useful

Comment: What tool did you use to make the USB? Try making your USB installer using **Etcher** in either Windows or Linux. https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: Pressing any of the F2, F12, ESC, DEL, etc. just takes me back to the grub rescue> prompt

Comment: I made a supposedly bootable Ubuntu 20 LTS USB key which seems to be identified as (hd1) but shows no partition and in another computer running Ubuntu 18 set to boot from the USB, it doesn't boot into Ubuntu 20. HOW CAN I GET TO THE BIOS TO BOOT THIS COMPUTER INTO A VERSION OF UBUNTU THAT WORKS?

Answer (score 0):

Just powered my AA1 up.
F2 - press rapidly as power button pressed brings me to BIOS.
Might be worth ensuring you have the latest BIOS - downloads and instructions on ACER site. Had to do that for my Z1 rebuild (SSD variant). I have 2 HD versions such as yours too so can provide a little experience.
BIOS upgrade is possible without having access to it and may help or at least allow access to the BIOS.

Might be worth taking the HD out and putting in a caddy attached to another machine to pull all your data off and/or check partitions and formats are as you expect.This is straight forward and many teardown guides are available - it's a couple of screws on the back.

I am assuming you cannot find /root/dev on any of your ls of your mountable partitions.

If you have an external CD-ROM you may be able to run a recovery linux.
DVD-rom may or may not be recognised depending on bios. This assumes you previously set boot order to these before HD for just this scenario..
This applies to a USB key too if you had previously set boot from this prior to HD. My paranoia means I usually leave this sort of thing set, recognising it allows for access if you don't keep physical control.

Sorry can't use comments yet so it is an answer...

also helpful would be : [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)