# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in grub rescue

Tags: grub2, virtualization

Different from other topics I have found. I have an ubuntu VM, mounted what I thought was a USB (as they are normally sda1) and without checking copied a file onto it. Well this stupid VM has its file system as sda1 and copied a file into it. As soon as I did that the VM crashed and went into grub rescue. When I run ls I get (hd0), (hd0,msdos1). So (hd0,msdos1) seems to be my filesystem, however ls (hd0,msdos1) returns : Filesystem is unknown. ls (hd0) returns unknown filesystem. I already set prefix =(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub and set root=(hd0,msdos1). insmod normal returns : unknown filesystem, normal returns: unknown command 'normal'. Does anyone know how to fix this? Since I am on a VM I don't think I can even boot from USB or anything. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Why is a VM any different to real hardware?  It's a virtual machine, so you boot a *live* system in the VM just like you would a real machine; the *virtualization* software controls how you do that, ie. you do it differently if using `virtualbox`, VMWare, etc...  but what you do is the same as if it where a real machine.  *Assuming a USB would be sda1 seems risky to me, the letters can change whenever a setting is changed in your virtualization software, so don't assume anything unless you like fixing problems*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

Comment: You can boot the VM from the same .iso that you would burn onto a USB (at least if it's virtualbox, the only one I know).